# Динамическое добавление данных из формы в БД PHP + SQL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, foreach

Необходимо добавить динамические данные из формы в Базу данных.
С помощью foreach, вывожу данные на страницу. Насколько я понимаю ошибка в скрытом инпуте, необходимо задавать динамически name. Я пробовал вместо `name="question_id"` писать `name="<?= 'question_id' . $question_id += 1 ?>"` . В результате данные выводились динамически после отправки формы (но в БД эти данные не попадали)

```
<?php
$question = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `question`");
$question = mysqli_fetch_all($question);
?>

<h3>add new users</h3>
<form action="vendor/create.php" method="POST">

    <?php
    $count = 1;
    // динамический вывод input из БД
    foreach ($question as $question) {
    ?>
        <div>
            <fieldset class="rating">
                <legend class="rating__caption"> 
                    <!-- вывод заголовка -->
                    <?= $question[0] ?> <?= $question[1] ?> 
                </legend>
                <div class="rating__group">
                    <input class="rating__star" type="radio" name="<?= $question[1] ?>" value="1" aria-label="Ужасно" />
                    <input class="rating__star" type="radio" name="<?= $question[1] ?>" value="2" aria-label="Плохо" />
                    <input class="rating__star" type="radio" name="<?= $question[1] ?>" value="3" aria-label="Нормально" />
                    <input class="rating__star" type="radio" name="<?= $question[1] ?>" value="4" aria-label="Хорошо" />
                    <input class="rating__star" type="radio" name="<?= $question[1] ?>" value="5" aria-label="Отлично" />
                </div>
                <!-- скрытое поле для внешнего ключа -->
                <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?= $count++ ?>">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Пытаюсь записать полученные данные в БД. Насколько я понимаю ошибка в данной части кода, я неправильно передаю данные через foreach. Записывается лишь одно значение для `A_QUESTION_ID`

```
<?php
require_once '../connect.php';
print_r($_POST);

$client = $_POST['id_client']; // id клиента
$value_answer = $_POST[$question[1]]; // ответ на input radio
$question_id = $_POST['question_id']; // скрытый input который хранит внешний ключ

// динамически добавляем данные в БД
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value_answer) {
    if ($value_answer != "" && $key != 'question_id') // $key != 'question_id' убираем лишнее значение 
     {
        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `ansver` (`ID_CLIENT`, `VALUE`, `A_QUESTION_ID`) VALUES (NULL, '$value_answer', '$question_id') ");
    }
}

// header('location: /');
```

Результат выполнения кода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В итоге имеем, то что в столбец `A_QUESTION_ID` , записывается лишь одно значение из скрытого инпута "5", результат должен быть "1", "2", "3", "4", "5". Значения в `VALUE`, записываются верные, все инпуты которые отмечены. Проблема в скрытом инпуте и его добавлении в БД. Прошу помочь с моей проблемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема в том что у вас пять скрытых полей с одинаковым именем **question_id** и передается только "последние" значение.
Вам надо каким-либо образом обеспечить уникальное имя для каждого из этих поле.

Но в общем-то не совсем понятно зачем вам это поле в форме. Можно просто использовать счетчик уже при обработке данных и при добавлении их в базу.

Comment: Я так делал, выше приводил пример, передавалось уникальное значение для **question_id** `name="<?= 'question_id' . $question_id += 1 ?>"`  , но тогда вообще никакие данные не выводятся в БД.

Comment: Это поле необходимо для БД, чтобы передавать уникальный ключ который соответствует значению вопроса. Потому что *question_id* будет являться внешним ключом в БД.

Comment: Решил в итоге сделать вариант, который вы предложили. Всё работает, но пока не до конца понимаю не приведет ли это к ошибкам, если в дальнейшем будут добавляться вопросы в бд. Спасибо за ответ!